# Green and red wire connected together on terminal

Tags: thermostat

I am installing a smart thermostat but I found the old thermostat has the green and red wires both running to the g terminal. When installing the new thermostat I will be removing the jumper wire between RC & RH. I do not have a heat pump ac unit only I live in south FL.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there was no answerable question asked.

Answer (score 1):

If you look very closely you'll see the red wire is on R and the green wire is on G. It just looks like the red and green are tied together on G.

Comment: Oh now I see that ! Wow it’s funny the older you get the more  depth perception changes I guess that’s why I’m always peeing on my shoes !   THANKS FOR THE HELP !

Comment: No problem! I just noticed the little copper ends sticking out.